# Why does not work macros response in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use macros to customize JSON response:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class ResponseMacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {

        public function boot()
        {
            Response::macro('caps', function ($value) {
                return Response::make(strtoupper($value));
            });
        }
    }
```

After I have registered `ResponseMacroServiceProvider` in `app.php` in section `providers`.

Then in controller I call macros response:

```
return response()->caps('foo');
```

It says messages:

> Method Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::caps does not exist.

Comment: You can try `php artisan optimize:clear` to clean the cache. It also might be helpful to add a dd(`booted`) at the beginning of your boot method to see if the provider is called or not

Comment: You must use `Response` object from namespace `Illuminate\Http` instead of `Illuminate\Support\Facades`

Comment: @bjovanov the use statement is correct. You have to use the facade (the example is taken from the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#response-macros))

Comment: Thank you `php artisan optimize:clear` it halped!

Comment: @mdexp You're totally right. My bad !

Comment: @user3573738 I posted that as an answer so you can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `php artisan optimize:clear` to clean the cache files.

It also might be helpful to add a dd(booted) at the beginning of your boot method to see if the provider is called or not